# Is there a proper function to merge two lists and flatten at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of say names, and then a list of lists with different attributes for each name (position of the name is equivalent to the position of the attribute list). I would like to combine these lists into a list of tuples with the following structure: `[(name, attribute), ...]`

Sample Code:

```
names = ['alice', 'bob']
attributes = [['tall', 'blue eyes'], ['small']]

finished_list = SomeMagicFunction(names, attributes)

finished_list
[('alice', 'tall'), ('alice', 'blue eyes'), ('bob', 'small')]
```

I know that the list comprehension mentioned below works (in combination with `zip()`), but I was wondering if there is a proper function out there that can do this.

```
test = list(zip(names, attributes))
[(tuple[0], attribute) for tuple in test for attribute in tuple[1]]
[('alice', 'tall'), ('alice', 'blue eyes'), ('bob', 'small')]
```

Comment: By "proper function" do you mean a handmade implementation of the ```list(zip())``` method you mentioned? Or rather one siingle clean function call that contains the code?

Comment: @ethanmorton Thanks for your clarifying question. With "proper function" I mean some standard function similar to `zip()`, `itertools.product()`, etc. as this seems to be a fairly standard problem in my opinion.

Comment: In some sense, using ```list(zip())``` is that more general function you're looking for. As you mentioned, the generator aspect is I think essentially what you are asking. Most Python developers (at least that I've met) would see ```list(zip())``` and think of it as a very clean implementation already, essentially like one function call, so noone has implemented an abstraction of it.

Comment: @ethanmorton Ok, I guess it just felt weird to me. Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard function, but that list comprehension is perfectly fine, though it could be more idiomatic:

1. No need for intermediate list `test`
2. Unpack so that you can use descriptive names like `for name, attrs in zip...`

```
>>> [(name, attr) for name, attrs in zip(names, attributes) for attr in attrs]
[('alice', 'tall'), ('alice', 'blue eyes'), ('bob', 'small')]
```